# Configure S3 to request from server when an object is not found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have images on S3 that need thumbnailing, and ideally, uploading back to S3. My understanding is that there is a way to configure S3 so that it makes a request (or redirects?) to my own server when an object is not found?

I'm thinking I could us that and generate thumbnails, then return that to the user and upload to S3 so that it can then be served off S3.

Is this possible and if so how would I go about doing that? I can't seem to find any documentation of the functionality, perhaps I'm not Googling the right thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for a CDN in pull mode.

[Read this for an inkling on how that might work using Amazon, Wordpress and a thumbnail plugin for it](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/11/timthumb-cdn-amazon-s3-good/).